# Firebase dynamic link always open web version instead of Google play

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

App not installed. Clicking to firebase dynamic link lead to browser and open web content.
I am using this dynamic link: https://market.page.link/?link=https://market.kz/cabinet
I followed this doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually
I tried specify afl and apn but it didnt help.

Comment: It would be better if you share your code like how you setup up your Manifest file and dynamic link code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems not be under developpers control. I had this problem too because i was always testing with the same app when opening the firebase dynamic link (Skype mobile).

I could not tell you exactly which app are causing this problem, but i can tell you that if you open a firebase dynamic link using skype in your Android device (strangely, it works fine with iOs), it will redirect to your browser at the Google play page.

You should try using another mobile app and open the link and see if it works. I tried facebook messenger and telegram and it works fine.

See more here : https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/2828